# How to install the Selenium IDE in Windows Firefox?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I use the Selenium IDE a lot in firefox when on my mac or Ubuntu machine.

How can I get the add-on working in Firefox on Windows?   I go through firefox add-ons and I find a lot of Selenium related stuff.  But not the actual IDE itself.

Comment: On the http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ page, in the "Selenium IDE" section, there is a link to http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/2.9.0/selenium-ide-2.9.0.xpi. Does that do the trick for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Search for Selenium IDE,
download latest released version

Example:

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/2.9.0/selenium-ide-2.9.0.xpi